# Automated incremental backups from Plesk on Centos to Amazon S3

Tags: backup, centos, plesk, amazon-s3

I've done a far bit of research on this via Google and there seems to be quite a few ways of possibly doing this.

I'm looking to incrementally backup new and updated files in two directories on my Plesk run Centos 5.2 server: /backups and /var/www/vhosts (preferable only httdocs within each vhost)

Has anyone got some great feedback from using the various solutions - seems to be various Java, Perl and Ruby based solutions out there.

Many thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

I use http://s3tools.org/s3tools and the tool S3cmd in a cron job to upload all the stuff I want to back up. I know of people that use SVN and then just back that up.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - the best solution I've found is Jungle Disk

https://www.jungledisk.com/

it's a snap to set up!

Comment: Did you set it up without any issues? Last time I tried JungleDisk v3 on Centos, it didn't work at all, so I'm still on their v2 version...